# What is the accurate translation of Hebrews 6:1, "...let us cease to speak of the beginning of Christ..."?

Tags: greek, hebrews

Hebrews 6:1 (DRB):

> Wherefore **leaving the word of the beginning of Christ**, let us go on to things more perfect, not laying again the foundation of penance from dead works, and of faith towards God,

The phrase:"leaving the word of the beginning of Christ" is a little confusing in other translations.

It is in DRB, and Darby, and Aramic Bible in plain English is somehow clear and literal and faithful to the original Greek text, and Latin Vulgate.

But it is in many other translations like KJV, ASV and ESV, is confusing. How to leave the doctrine of the first principles of Christ?

We can construct a phrase of DRB and ERV (English Revised Version) which may be very clear and accurate. The phrase in ERV is:

> ...let us cease to speak of the first principles of Christ, ...

Thus we can say:

"...let us cease to speak of the beginning of Christ..."

I hope you give me the most accurate translation of this phrase.

I hope you give an explanation of the phrase, and the whole verse.

Answer (score 2):

I am no Greek scholar so someone else may have a better answer on this but it seems rather simple that ἀρχῆς τοῦ does not modify χριστοῦ, it modifies λόγον therefore, the better rendering in English would seem to be "Leaving the beginning teachings of (or about) Christ," This translation seems a bit awkward in English. A more comfortable rendering may be represented by the NAS, "Therefore leaving the elementary teaching about the Christ...."

Answer (score 1):

The grammar means that it must be understood thus: the principle word of Christ.

It is a classic 'Hebrew genitive' structure (such as "the son of his love" [his most beloved son] or "the mountain of his holiness" [his holy mountain]).

In context "the word of the beginning of Christ" refers to **the rudimentary doctrines of Christianity,** such as ordinations, baptism, repentance, faith, resurrection, judgement, etc.

λογος in Greek (here translated word) has a wider range of meaning than it does in modern English, and here seems to mean (a word given concerning some topic; treatise, a treatment of a topic, etc. - similar to how we might say, 'can we have a word,' when we mean, 'can we discuss something').

Implying they are already familiar with and have been taught about such, he goes on to discuss the relationship between justification and how we live as pertains to salvation, more in depth, and substantiates it with Old Testament passages.

He prefaces this by complaining that his audience ought to be themselves 'teachers' in the 'elementary things' of God already, but are not.